# Prolem with encoding URL parametes which include %

Tags: javascript, url, urlencode, url-encoding

I face a problem with encoding URL query, in my application it's search URL.
For example, here is a peace of code:

```
url_path = 'domain.com/search?query=' + search_phrase;
```

Yes, I can use method *encodeURIComponent()* and it works:

```
url_path = 'domain.com/search?query=' + encodeURIComponent(search_phrase);
```

But when user search for a phrase which include symbols like '%' - it generates broken request. And in results I have 500 response with error:

```
URIError: malformed URI sequence
```

How can I encode URI parameters to prevent current problem?
If I am wrong in something or don't understand correctly how it works, please explain me it.
Kindly thanks for help.

Comment: No, not the request is broken, `%` is suppsed to be encoded as `%25`. If your server thinks that would be malformed, fix your server. Or what exactly are you doing with that `url_path`?

Comment: @Bergi, do I always need to encode URI query before sending request to backend? is it so necessary at all? thanks for an answer

Comment: @Bergi for example if user setup page encoding in his browser from utf8 to smthing else, I will have problems with it?

Comment: Yes, you need to encode URI parameters, or otherwise a user could trivially produce really malformed URIs by entering arbitrary stuff. No, page encoding does not have any effects on this (and I doubt a user can setup anything but the default to be used when the server doesn't provide an encoding).